# How do I get user input on a jForm?

Tags: java, input, jform

I can use numbers and stuff like

```
num1 = Float.parseFloat(txt1.getText());
```

but I am looking to get words from a text field, then do calculations based on which word. Like:

```
String input1;
if (input1.equalsIgnorecase("Word")) {
2 + 2; }
```

I just don't know how to do that on a jform.

Comment: just add a blank line before you enter code

Comment: `String text = txt1.getText()`?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @MadProgrammer, .getText() will help you in retrieving String values from a test field.

For example, If your Java Form contains a text field whose variable name is jTextField1, you can retreive value from it by:

```
String input1 = jTextFielf1.getText();
```

Just for information,

```
float num1 = Float.parseFloat(txt1.getText());
```

also does the same thing, it first gets the string value from the text field and converts it into a float value.